# insmod parameters and $ sign

Tags: shell, quoting, kernel-modules

I am tinkering with device driver programming under Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and came across a strange behavior; hope you can shed some light on.

`sudo insmod hello.ko whom="$"` yields the expected output:

> Hello $ (0) !!!

but `sudo insmod hello.ko whom="$$"` yields:

> Hello 3275 (0) !!!

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static char *whom = "world";
static int howMany = 1;

static int __init  hello_init(void){
int i;
for(i = 0; i < howMany; i++){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello %s (%d) !!!\n", whom, i);
    }
return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void){
printk(KERN_ALERT "Bye bye %s !!!\n", whom);
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
module_param(howMany, int, S_IRUGO);
module_param(whom, charp, S_IRUGO);
```

Comment: `sudo insmod hello.ko whom="\$"` does the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to do with the kernel, it's just that `$$` expands to the shell's process id, see e.g. [Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters).

> ($$) Expands to the process ID of the shell. In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the invoking shell, not the subshell.

Escape the dollar sign with a backslash, or use single-quotes to prevent the expansion:

```
$ echo "$$" "\$$" '$$'
29058 $$ $$
```